Error while redirecting using ESAPI HTTPUtilities used for CWE-113 fix
I am getting below error while redirecting to another url using ESAPI . I am unable to resolve CWE-113 issues due to this. could anyone please help.
<pre>org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: SecurityConfiguration for HttpUtilities.maxRedirectLength has incorrect type</pre><h3>Processing Info:</h3>
Below are my code and dependencies.
I have tried below code by commenting previous code to fix CWE-113.

ESAPI.httpUtilities().setCurrentHTTP(request,response);

try {

   ESAPI.httpUtilities().sendRedirect(myURL);

} catch (AccessControlException e) {

   throw new RuntimeException(e);
} ESAPI.httpUtilities().clearCurrent();

\<dependency\>

\<groupId\>org.owasp.esapi\</groupId\>

\<artifactId\>esapi\</artifactId\>

\<version\>2.2.3.1\</version\>
\</dependency\> 


It’s pretty clear.  Whatever value you have in your properties file for your HttpUtilities.maxRedirectLength is the wrong type.

This is an example of getting so flustered by a problem that you miss the obvious solution:

<pre>org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: SecurityConfiguration for HttpUtilities.maxRedirectLength has incorrect type</pre><h3>Processing Info:</h3> 

In ESAPI.properties there is a key/value mapping where the key is HttpUtilities.maxRedirectLength
You have a configuration exception, that should always point you to ESAPI.properties or validation.properties
The warning you're getting is that value is not of the correct type.  Likely there's either text or the value is empty.  But that's it in a nutshell.

I am pointing those details to default values like below. But not sure how it is throwing errors.
ESAPI.HTTPUtilities=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultHTTPUtilities

So without a project I can spin up on a local machine and set up a debugger, there’s not much else I can suggest.  Something is interfering with your library loading.  The only other time I’ve seen this behavior is when ESAPI was getting loaded by the web server that my app was running on.  (Cold fusion does this.)
